# Proxy not found while using cordova-plugin-printer isavailable function in ionic-native/printer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Installed :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
npm install --save @ionic-native/printer
```

On button click used:

```
this.prnt.isAvailable().then(function()
    {
      alert("available");
    },function(){
      alert("not available");
    });
```

Error Received :

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: Printer :: check
```

Please advice how to remove this error!

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late but someone else will find this useful.
**As you can see on the documentation it's won't support on browser even if you run with cordova. Try to run this on a real device it will work.**[See image for supported devices info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmDE1.png)

Comment: oh Ehh! You better check